# Android - Trouble in getting location coordinates by only using GPS provider

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location, locationlistener

I am new to android. So please apologize if my question is simple and help me.

I am developing an android app in which I try to get users location **only using GPS service** (As I am developing an app which needs to run in android devices even with **no internet**).

My code is given below:

**My activity:**

```
public class MyView extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Runnable
    {
       LocationManager itsLocationManager;
       LocationListener itsLocationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      itsLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      itsLocationListener = new MyLocationListener(this, itsLocationManager);

      getLocationAndSendMessage();
    }

    private void getLocationAndSendMessage() 
    {
      try 
      {
        itsLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, itsLocationListener);
      } 
      catch (Exception theException) 
      {
        theException.printStackTrace();
        ToastMsgUtil.showErrorMessage("Problem in retrieving your current location! Please try again.", this);  
       }
     }
```

**MyLocationListener.java:**

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    Context itsContext;
    LocationManager itsLocationManager;

    public MyLocationListener(Context theContext, LocationManager theLocationManager) 
    {
        itsContext = theContext;
        itsLocationManager = theLocationManager;
    }

        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location theLocation) 
    {
                //My Location processing code
                itsLocationManager.removeUpdates(SafemateLocationListener.this);
         }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

As I said above, I need to get location only through GPS (as no internet in users mobile).

- On debugging, I found that I am **not receiving any location updates** in **onLocationChanged** method when I am using **LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER**.
- However, when I tried with **LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER**, I receive location updates.

Can anyone please say what I did wrong in the above code? Have I missed any thing?

Help please. Thank You.

Comment: There are a lot of sample in blogs, in stackoverflow, in android dev guide. New locations will arrive in your onLocationChanged method. Your getLocationAndSendMessage method is just register your location listener. And you don't need implement Runnable in your Activity class

Comment: @Kamal if you found any solutin then pls post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting correct coordinates using GPS in a stable, working and compatible way is a mess. I remember a posting somewhere here at stackoverflow.com but can't find it at the moment. So I'd suggest to take the GPS-related code out of [WLocate.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/libwlocate/code/ci/641b5fa038398364c7fe3fc996744ae094f0cc49/tree/master/android/LocDemo/src/com/vwp/libwlocate/WLocate.java) which works using all known Android versions. Or use the [libwlocate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwlocate/), it encapsulates the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. If I am not wrong, libwlocate is use to get user's location using the WLAN-networks that are available near to a particular point. In my case, if there is no WLAN-networks nearer to me, then do I get my geolocation values? Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: libwlocate can do both: getting location via GPS and/or WLAN - it is up to you to choose which of the options has to be used. You can limit it to GPS location too.