# Location manager of android giving some meters of position error

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I already posted this question related to location manager

[location-manager-is-not-working-without-internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112140/location-manager-is-not-working-without-internet)

Now it is working outside under the sky without internet and only using GPS .
Code is same.But now the problem is positions are not accurate . It is giving some meters of error. I am calling this java piece of code from javascript through cordova plugin .

Is it the reason for my less accuracy?? If not how can i write code for best accuracy?
location listener is not giving proper locations

Answer (score 0):

I use cordova. If you've set "enableHighAccuracy" at true, you use the GPS.
You can catch the Accuracy with this : position.Accuracy.
I have work so many time with three devices at same place and they sent a different position (less than 10 m different). It depends on the device and the environment, not the software : Cordova use the native locationmanager in Android.
If you have other questions or comments......

Coco

Comment: U r saying less than 10m . That is fine actually. But i am getting more than 10 m error. 40m sometimes :(

Comment: What's your devices and your environment ? are they building or other ?

Comment: outside building . samsung s2 is the device

Comment: I have set enableHighAccuracy:true

Comment: Maybe S2 is not very accurate. I used a HTC one touch and S3, and it wasn't the same thing.... Can you try with an other device ? If not, try this : http://www.genymotion.com/ . It's Very VERY usefull !

Comment: genymotion.com?? Is it possible to test in that as real testing??

Comment: not only s2 i tried with different different mobiles .. Result is same .. gps location error :(

Comment: Genymotion allow you to emulate the GPS: you fix the location with a google map, the accuracy, and the orientation. I dont know why you have so bad location. Maybe there is not enough satellites over you  :-D . Does postion.accuracy says 40 ? or is it your observations ?

Comment: Not observation. position.accuracy says 40

Comment: do you know how to developp in native android ? if yes, make a small app just to see the accuracy. because I dont know why you have these results...

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be under the sky **but near buildings**? Next to where I work (and test) I have annoying over 10m error, but on a meadow or far from any tall building it works pretty decently. Other than that, I guess it might be a device issue.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy of location manager depends upon various things such as distance from buildings, satellites orbiting right above you at the very instant, device age, device gps quality etc.

Also in your AndroidManifest.xml add the permisson-

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Answer (score 0):

you can request to google to get the nearest position in street, I am coding tracking app , this is my solution to limit accurate.

try link : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false